# How to check if std::max_element returned an element?

Tags: c++

I'm learning about `std::max_element`. I wrote the following code:

```
auto e = std::max_element(
                    std::begin(rtspUrls), std::end(rtspUrls),
                    [](const RTSPUrl &p1, const RTSPUrl &p2) {
                        unsigned int area1 = p1.resolution().width() * p1.resolution().height();
                        unsigned int area2 = p2.resolution().width() * p2.resolution().height();
                        return area1 < area2;
                    });
```

but one thing that I could not understand is how I am sure that I have an element in `e`. It could be that the set `rtspUrls` is empty. My `e` has type `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<RTSPUrl>` for which I dont know how to check if it points to something.

Comment: `if(rtspUrls.empty())`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/):

> **Return value**
>
> An iterator to largest value in the range, or last if the range is empty.

So to check if it actually returned something, you compare it against `std::end(rtspUrls)`. If it's equal, then it didn't. If it's not equal to that, then it returned something, and you can access it via dereferencing, i.e. `*e`.

```
if (e == std::end(rtspUrls)) {
  // No return
} else {
  // Use *e to get the value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `rtspUrls` is empty, `max_element` returns the second parameter you passed in (the iterator to the last element), i.e. `std::end(rtspUrls)`